# Is there a cross-platform way to disable deprecated warnings in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a library, and I am refactoring some functionality. I marked some old methods with `itkLegacyMacro` defined below. These deprecated methods are being called from the library's own unit tests. Is there a way to disable deprecation warnings which will work across all (or at least most) compilers?

itkLegacyMacro:

```
// Setup compile-time warnings for uses of deprecated methods if
// possible on this compiler.
#if defined( __GNUC__ ) && !defined( __INTEL_COMPILER ) && ( __GNUC__ > 3 || ( __GNUC__ == 3 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 1 ) )
#define itkLegacyMacro(method) method __attribute__( ( deprecated ) )
#elif defined( _MSC_VER )
#define itkLegacyMacro(method) __declspec(deprecated) method
#else
#define itkLegacyMacro(method) method
#endif
```

Method definition in library proper:

```
class X {
itkLegacyMacro(void oldMethod());
void newMethod(); }
```

Method invocation from unit test:

```
X testX;
testX.newMethod(); //test the new stuff
testX.oldMethod(); //test the old stuff too!
```

The last line causes a warning to be emitted when compiled. I would like this library to test the deprecated functionality, but not have warnings when compiled. Is that possible? C++11 is being used.

Comment: Warnings are generally compiler specific. Is it something "deprecated" in a specific library, or for a specific compiler, or actually in the standard?

Comment: I am a library maintainer, and with the new version some methods should be deprecated. I am attaching `__declspec(deprecated)` to them. Is there a way to have library's own unit tests not produce a warning when compiled?

Comment: I can't say definitively, but not that I can find. Although you could try adding the relevant #pragmas or command line options in whatever your make engine is, for every compiler you can think of, or add your own preprocessor switch to not build or use the deprecated functions in some build configurations.

Comment: What's `__declspec`? As far as I'm aware `__declspec` itself is not cross-platform.

Comment: Can't you just redefine your macro and stop generating the warnings?

Comment: @GemTaylor that was basically the solution. The macro already inspected a certain `#define`, I just needed to define it in the test.

Comment: Yes, I read the later comments to the "answer", which didn't afterwards. Glad you are happy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know `__declspec(...)` is a Microsoft extension and is not cross-plattform anyway.

You could use macros to control this

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define DEPRECATED __declspec(deprecated)
#else 
#define DEPRECATED
#endif

DEPRECATED void someDeprecatedFunction()
```

There is also `[[deprecated("because")]]` since C++14.

To turn it off only for unit tests, you could do something like

```
#ifndef SUPPRESS_DEPRECATE_FUNCTIONS
#define DEPRECATED __declspec(deprecated)
#else
#define DEPRECATED
#endif
```

and then `#define SUPPRESS_DEPRECATE_FUNCTIONS` in your unit test, or compile with `-DSUPPRESS_DEPRECATE_FUNCTIONS`. Or you could create a special header in your unit tests which `#pragma` the warning suppression. Something along the lines of

```
#if defined( __GNUC__ ) && !defined( __INTEL_COMPILER ) && ( __GNUC__ > 3 || ( __GNUC__ == 3 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 1 ) )
#pragma for gcc
#elif defined( _MSC_VER )
#pragma for msvc
#else
// nothing
#endif

#include "your_library_header.h"
```

The unit tests then only include this header before any other of your library headers.

Comment: I could kick myself in the groin right now. The `itkLegacyMacro` already had a way to disable warning, by `#define ITK_LEGACY_TEST` using a mechanism similar to your proposed `SUPPRESS_DEPRECATE_FUNCTIONS`. And I could have read that just a few lines above!